# how to check the terraform configuration is complete for AWS RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

How do I check if the terraform configuration I created for AWS RDS Instance does not miss anything? I am trying to create the RDS for Aurora MySQL 5.7 and I keep getting errors. I want to know how can I know my configuration does not miss any parameters?

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?  In general, you know you don't miss any configuration parameters by diligently checking your configuration and seeing if anything is missing when you test the config.

Comment: You should show both your code and the errors you're getting if you want someone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `terraform plan` before running `terraform apply`.

- plan will show the errors if there are any missing arguments. Plan will not create any resources but will create the execution plan. For more info, refer [Terraform plan](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html)
- Also there is chance that plan might succeed and apply might fail due to other reasons.